# Method injection (DI, .NET, IOC)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am using .NET (MVC5, Web API etc). I understand constructor injection just about (fairly new to using it in anger).
I have a class with a method that has a dependency. I don't want to use constructor injection because then I will be creating the dependent object every time this class is instantiated (and most of the methods don't use this dependent object).
So I thought method injection sounded like it might be the thing. However I can't figure out how to do it (I am using Autofac).

So if my method is
void DoSomething(string x, int y)
and that method needs to use an implementation of IMyService, how do I do this without using the constructor injection?

The only method injection technique I have seen is one where effectively a method is called at instantiation. This doesn't seem to help my case, it still means that all instances create this dependency even if I am going to call a method that doesn't need it.

I'm sure it is something simple but I can't figure it out right now. Could you help me with an example please?

*UPDATE*

this is the crux of it. I like the idea of Lazy suggested by Jim and will try this. So is method injection as I suspected and if so I don't really understand the point of it - why use it instead of constructor injection?

```
public class MailService { 
   // lots of methods that don't need PlayerDataService 
   public void SendPlayersEmail() { 
       var service = new PlayerDataService(); 
       var players = service.GetPlayers(); 
       foreach(var player in players) { 
           SendEmail(player); 
       } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question and show some code that describes your particular case more specifically? If possible, use the real class, interface, method and parameter names, because often this context is important.

Comment: this is the crux of it. I like the idea of Lazy suggested by Jim and will try this. So is method injection as I suspected and if so I don't really understand the point of it - why use it instead of constructor injection?

public class MailService
{
lots of methods that don't need PlayerDataService

public void SendPlayersEmail()
{
var service = new PlayerDataService();
var players = service.GetPlayers();
foreach(var player in players)
{
SendEmail(player);
}
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cost of instantiating your object during construction is an issue, you can wrap it in a `Lazy<>` to avoid unnecessary construction. This will cause your dependency to be constructed on the first call to the lazy's `.Value`.

Comment: like this. So if my class level variable is defined as Lazy<T> and I want to use InstancePerDependency and I call Value twice in the same lifetime then I will get 2 separate instances? So if I want to reference the same service twice within the method I have to use .Value and save it in a variable and then use that variable? Then if I want a second instance I call .Value again?

Comment: If the cost of construction is an issue, there is probably something wrong because [constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and you should be able to [create object graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/). Although the use of `Lazy<T>` can be helpful, IMO @jgauffin's answer addresses the core issue.

Comment: I have used the Lazy<T> suggestion which works fine. Yes it is probably overkill and unnecessary but it is useful info anyway. 
I'd still like to know when you would use method injection instead of constructor injection.
Also I can set this up using RegisterType quite easily but can't figure out the syntax for Register using a lambda expression. Again,  just useful info for me and anyone else who may need to register using lambda and lazy types.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

> I don't want to use constructor injection because then I will be creating the dependent object every time this class is instantiated (and most of the methods don't use this dependent object).

There's the problem. Break that functionality out into a new class.

That is, at least in my experience, the best solution when a method does not fit into the rest of the class (or have dependencies that are not used anywhere else).

You should also consider that object allocation is pretty cheap, you need millions of allocations per second before the performance is hurt (unless you are using Ninject ;))

Comment: You're spot on here +1. The OP's update made it very clear. His code comment `lots of methods that don't need PlayerDataService` just made this very clear. He is violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and this bytes him immediately. Although the use of `Lazy<T>` can be helpful sometimes, Jim's answer does not address the core issue, while your answer does. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: ok. The MailService has one responsibility and that is to send emails of various sorts. One of these email jobs needs to get a list of players from another service. This breaks Single Responsibility? Not entirely convinced. I suppose I could have various EmailServices. Alternatively in the PLayerService I could have a SendEmail method but then that would be a service full of methods only one of which needed an EmailService.....

Comment: @user2047485 - I would say, the MailService have one responsibility and that is to send email. It should not necessarily have the responsibility of constructing those emails. Break this responsibility out into other classes, it will make your head hurt less.

Comment: if I am sending a specific email I have to construct it somewhere. If I need to send this email from various places I don't want to build the list in each place and send them in because that would repeat the work(and therefore have the same dependency in multiple places). I am removing the dependency in the mail service by allowing an injection of the service to build the player list. The  other option I see is to provide a service for this specific job but that can't be a good pattern? I can't see an obvious pattern for dealing with this. Though actually the Lazy initialisation works fine.

Comment: the point was rather that if you are sending emails from multiple places you would benefit to have the sending logic in one place (setting sender, finding a working SMTP server, dealing with delivery failures etc) in one place and just constructing the emails in the original place.